# Windows 8.1 Pro install - SSD not detected

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, drivers, ssd, thinkpad

Upgrading my girlfriend's Lenovo SL510 to use an SSD. I removed the old HDD and replaced it by the Samsung 830 128GB SSD. The SSD is visible in the BIOS and it is accessible/formattable from another Windows 8.1 computer.

I tried downloading the [storage drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS003639) and adding them to the Windows USB stick to no avail, it will not detect the SSD drivers. What's peculiar though: **in the folder selection to locate the driver I can see the single NTFS parition on the SSD**.

Update: using advanced tools of the Windows installation media, I can use the diskpart tool - it detects the SSD and everything seems to be working as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it by clearing the master boot record using `diskpart`'s `clean` option. The disk was originally used in a raid-0 configuration, which apparently makes it hard for windows to detect.